# Reason for Orbital Reflector

Tags: earth, artificial-satellite, near-earth-object

We know that last year, space X rocket took orbital reflector with it into the space. But what might be the reason behind launching this weird object into the space? Does it do any work there?
[image]

Comment: There's a somewhat related but unanswered question in Space SE: [Attitude of the upcoming “Orbital Reflector”; will it result in good visibility?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30878/12102). Space SE is a good site to ask this question, since it's about launching an artificial satellite into low Earth orbit for artistic purposes, not about Astronomy proper. I'm voting to close as off-topic. That doesn't mean it's a bad question, just that it's not on-topic in Astronomy SE. It might be a good idea to simply post this there, and then delete it here; faster than closing and possible migration

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Astronomy as defined in the help center https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic